# How to pipe cURL verbose output to logging module?

Tags: python, curl

Does anyone know how or if it's possible to redirect cURL verbose output to the logging module? Right now the verbose output is all going to stdout, but I'd like to pipe it to logging.debug which is being saved to a file.

Note that I don't want to pipe all console output to logging. Also, I do have a string buffer to capture the pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION however that doesn't seem to capture the VERBOSE output.

current code:

```
logging.debug('starting setopt_put for url: %s',api_url)
self._podium_curl_setopt_base(api_url.url + api_args)
self._podium_curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPGET, 1)
self._podium_curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self._string_buffer.write)
self._podium_curl.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
self._podium_curl.perform()
logging.info(_string_buffer.getvalue())
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you doing it right now? What do you mean by `stdout`, where are you calling curl?

Comment: Added code for how I'm doing it now, WRITEFUNCTION parameter captures regular cURL output, but the verbose info is only making it o stdout/console, it's not going to the same string buffer, which can then be used as appropriate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

curl has a `DEBUGFUNCTION` callback option that works in a similar way to the `WRITEFUNCTION` option, except that it gets called with the VERBOSE output instead of the response body.

The [official documentation](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/callbacks.html#debugfunction) has reference information as well as a short example, which you should be able to adapt to your needs:

```
def test(debug_type, debug_msg):
    print "debug(%d): %s" % (debug_type, debug_msg)

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://curl.haxx.se/")
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, test)
c.perform()
```